# Option String in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, option-type

I have a library that returns a `Some String` i.e. an optional string to me.

What does this mean - I have received a non-empty string? Or I have received a string that can be empty? In general, who determines the semantics of `Some` for a type ? Does the language specify it for base types?

Thanks!

Comment: An example could be ``div_string : int -> int -> string option``, which performs division and gives back the result in string. If the second argument is ``0``, the function can return a ``None``, which is of type ``string option``. This result indicates an invalid operation was performed.

Comment: The definition of that type : `type 'a option = None | Some of 'a` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `Some x` is a *value*, not a type. The type returned by the library would be `string option`. If you happen to know that the value always looks like `Some x`, that's a different question. But it's also pretty unlikely, as the library author could just use the type `string` for that. You use an option type specifically so you can use `None` to represent the absence of a value.

I'd say the type `'a option` has the same semantics for every type `'a`. The type `'a option` represents a value of the type that can either be present or not. If the value is present, it takes the form `Some x`, where `x` is a value of the type. If the value isn't present, it takes the form `None`.

A value of type `string option` can be `None`, or it can be `Some ""`, or it can be `Some "xxx"` for any string `"xxx"`. There's no special string-specific meaning.